# Pandas - How to repeat dataframe n times each time adding a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I repeat the values in my dataframe n times while adding a new column in each repetition

I've tried and got the repetition of the values n times but I couldn't figure out how to add a new column. Here's my initial dataframe of randomly generated temperatures -

```
df1 = 
    temp
0   30
1   40
2   50
3   60
```

And I could replicate it n times using following code -

df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(df.values,2,axis=0))

Now I want the new df to have a new column called city and every new repetition to add a different value specified in the following list -

```
cities = ['Bangalore', 'Hyderabad'] //no. of cities will be same as n

expected output -
df2 = 
    temp city
0   30   Bangalore
1   40   Bangalore
2   50   Bangalore
3   60   Bangalore
4   30   Hyderabad
5   40   Hyderabad
6   50   Hyderabad
7   60   Hyderabad
```

How can I get this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Using `DataFrame.assign` & `pd.concat`:

We loop over each city in your `cities` list and `assign` it as a new column. Then we use `concat` to concatenate the separate dataframes to one final dataframe.

```
final = pd.concat([df1.assign(city=c) for c in cities], ignore_index=True)
```

**Output**

```
   temp       city
0    30  Bangalore
1    40  Bangalore
2    50  Bangalore
3    60  Bangalore
4    30  Hyderabad
5    40  Hyderabad
6    50  Hyderabad
7    60  Hyderabad
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `numpy.tile` and `numpy.repeat`:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

temps = [30, 40, 50, 60]
cities = ['Bangalore', 'Hyderabad']

temp = np.tile(temps, len(cities))
city = np.repeat(cities, len(temps))
df = pd.DataFrame({"temp": temp, "city": city})
```

Output:

```
    temp    city
0   30  Bangalore
1   40  Bangalore
2   50  Bangalore
3   60  Bangalore
4   30  Hyderabad
5   40  Hyderabad
6   50  Hyderabad
7   60  Hyderabad
```

Comment: This is neat but for this I need to have my temp values in a list

Comment: I like your `numpy` approach, that's nice!

Answer (score 1):

using [`pandas.MultiIndex.from_product`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html)

```py
pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df['temp'], cities], names=['temp', 'city']) \
    .to_frame(index=False) \
    .sort_values('city')
```

```py
    temp    city
0   30  Bangalore
2   40  Bangalore
4   50  Bangalore
6   60  Bangalore
1   30  Hyderabad
3   40  Hyderabad
5   50  Hyderabad
7   60  Hyderabad
```